# Shortcut key to close tab within Firefox Developer Tools

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-developer-tools

Is there a keyboard shortcut to close the current Debugger (source file) tab within the Firefox Developer Tools (on MacOS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, so I assume it is <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> on MacOS.

Note that you need to have the file you want to close focused in the DevTools, otherwise the browser tab will be closed.

See also the [documentation of all DevTools keyboard shortcuts on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts) or [the one just for the Debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/Keyboard_shortcuts).

Comment: No, that closes the whole browser tab. I have made that mistake many times. I want to close one tab within the developer tools, only.

Comment: Did you have the DevTools focused?

Comment: Huh, seems it does work! But not only do you have to have the dev tools focused, but specifically one of the tabs within Debugger. Focusing on any of the other windows within the Dev Tools means the whole tab gets closed.

Comment: Good to hear! I've added the shortcuts to the documentation on MDN and added links to those pages to my answer.

Comment: As a user that is actually what I expect. I want to see what gets closed. Would be strange if the shortcut closed something in another panel.

Comment: I find it unintuitive. When the focus is on the console, I still really expect cmd-w to shut the current source tab, not the entire browser tab.

Comment: I agree that closing the browser tab is unexpected in that case. Personally, I'd expect it to do nothing in the console or any other panel that doesn't have tabs. I've filed a [bug report for changing the current behavior](https://bugzil.la/1640604). Feel free to post a comment there.